# Magento under WordPress as subdirectory not working

Tags: magento-1.5, wordpress, .htaccess

I am using GoDaddy server.

I have WordPress as root directory and i have setup Magento from local to server inside root as subdirectory.

Magento home page is working fine,but when i try to open any subpage of Magento then it opens "About us" page without CSS of root WordPress.

Here is my Magento site link:

- http://shreeyaitsolutions.com/sub-domains/magentostore/

Comment: it seems there is a problem with your .htaccess. Please share you .htaccess code]

Comment: This my root wordpress .htacces code,**bold**
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^cake/(.*)$ /sub-domains/dcm/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: its not a problem with WordPress code but with the Magento .htaccess `RewriteBase` should be `/sub-domains/magentostore/` in Magento .htaccess

Comment: I am writing it as an answer you can mark it as completed so it will be helpful for future users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the Rewrite in your **.htaccess**.

Open **.htaccess** of your Magento subdirectory and change `RewriteBase` to

```
/sub-domains/magentostore/
```